# Domain of a differentiable function contains an interval on which the function is either increasing or decreasing.

Tags: real-analysis

Let  be differentiable at  in a domain (,) and $f'(b)\neq0$.

Then does (,) contain an interval (,) such that  is either increasing or decreasing on (,)?

For example, = is differentiable at 1 in (0,2) with $f'(1)=1$ and (0,2) contains (0,1) on which = is increasing.

I was wondering this is true in general. Does $f'$ also have to be continuous?

Comment: If the derivative is continuous then yes.  If not then it’s doesn’t have to have this property.

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://mathoverflow.net/questions/167323/everywhere-differentiable-function-that-is-nowhere-monotonic&ved=2ahUKEwjD4IaU1oPwAhWM4J4KHWBpAk4QjjgwAnoECBYQAg&usg=AOvVaw1pf__h3AOhzf5z9giZqxT_